# USB Audio device no longer usable after reboot

Tags: audio, alma-linux, usb-audio

My AlmaLinux9 server has been running great for months, playing audio through a USB device which was detected during installation.  After a recent reboot I can no longer play audio because my app reports no sounds cards.

dmesg shows detection of my sound card:

```
[    2.035043] usb 3-1.2.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.102248] usb 2-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[    2.169381] usb 3-1.2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=08bb, idProduct=2902, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    2.169389] usb 3-1.2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.169394] usb 3-1.2.2: Product: USB Audio CODEC
[    2.169399] usb 3-1.2.2: Manufacturer: Burr-Brown from TI
[    2.174145] input: Burr-Brown from TI               USB Audio CODEC  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/0000:13:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2.2/3-1.2.2:1.3/0003:08BB:2902.0002/input/input6
[    2.225293] hid-generic 0003:08BB:2902.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [Burr-Brown from TI               USB Audio CODEC ] on usb-0000:13:00.0-1.2.2/input3
```

Yet Linux doesn't see this as a sound card:

```
 aplay -l
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

What happened?  And how do I fix this?

Comment: refer to: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=290782 and 
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1123747-start-0.html

Comment: highly likely there is a change in the kernel, and you have to re-enable something back to get it to work

Comment: Check if a driver is loaded for it with `lsusb -t` (snd-something). Also check if `aplay -l` gives different output when run as root.

Comment: aplay -l gave same output when run as root.  I have since run rebooted and sound has returned, but when it happens again I will update the post.